# How to know exact right time to duplicate the keycard?

Tags: payday-2

I'm a newbie with Payday 2.  When I saw people can duplicate the keycard I wondered why/how it works (e.g. when they say 20 and 1:20 minutes/second).  How do I duplicate the keycard?

Comment: I'm not sure we should be supporting deliberately glitching or exploiting bugs in online games.

Comment: @Frank - I wasn't sure on the site's stance.  You play Payday 2 *with* friends/others rather than against anyone I believe... if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Rasteve, you are correct. Payday 2 is a PvE game, with no PvP.

Comment: We are currently [attempting to define](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10317/cheats-in-multiplayer-games-are-banned-but-what-is-a-cheat) whether this would constitute a cheat or not.  Anyone who's interested, I encourage you to pitch in with your view.

Comment: Independently from the discussion on meta, I think that Payday 2 is a special case. The game is currently so broken in some aspects, especially synchronization, that using glitches like that feels like making up for all the times a mission failed because of a glitch.

Comment: @Sentry Also: [So you tell me that...](https://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/2df9kp/so_you_tell_me_that/)

Answer (score 15):

Others explained *how* this trick works; but you also asked *why* it works.

The reason it works is that most of the client computations are done client-side in Payday 2 *(this, along with the ridiculous ease of modding the engine, are also the reason hacks are so prevalent in this game)*.

So, when one person picks up the card, their computer tells the server *"Hey, I picked up this card"*.  The server then lets all the other clients know that the card has been picked up.  However, if *another* client picks up the card before they receive that message, then both clients will be holding the same card.

It would be entirely possible to detect this situation and take the card away from one of the clients; but the developers just haven't done that.

Source: Countless hours wading through the Payday 2 Lua code.

Comment: I first was going to mention the client side stuff in my answer, but I wasn't entirely sure I had it right so I left it out. Thanks for making that clear to me too!

Comment: I will also add that this can occur in reverse (so to speak) - two people can end up using the same item on the same interaction at the same time, which eats up both items but only actually uses it once. In some cases, this can "soft-lock" the mission requiring it to be restarted.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to dupe the keycard if you get every player to pick up the keycard at the same time on the in-game timer. That way it will appear in every player's inventory. If someone tells you "1:20" you need to watch the timer, and as it turns 1:20 you pick up the keycard. It's kind of an exploit but won't get you banned or anything.

This also works with some other items like thermal paste.

Answer (score 4):

Duping occurs when two or more players all try to pick up an item at the same time. The window of opportunity is small, but its possible to perform the trick quite consistently with practice.

This can be done by synchronising with the in game timer, or verbally. When I do this with the group I play with (on voicechat), we have the host start at "3..2..1..go" countdown. When you hear the host say go, you pick up the card. The host will delay pressing his button for a fraction of a second to account for lag in the voice chat.

The reverse can also happen, it is possible for two (or more) players to use a keycard each on the same door, effectively losing one of the cards.